# Unmanaged C++ tlh file not updating?

Tags: c++, interface, typelib

I have an IDL file with some interfaces in it.

```
[
   object,
   uuid(newguid),
   dual,
   helpstring("NewInterface Interface"),
   pointer_default(unique)
]
interface INewInterface: IOldInterface
{
   [id(newid), helpstring("method NewMethod")] HRESULT NewMethod([in] BSTR bstrParam );
}
```

But when I compile my code it does not see my new interface. Also when I open the .tlh file it has not been updated to display the new interface.

Any thoughts on what I need to do?

Edit:
Imports are made via

```
#import "File.tlb" raw_interfaces_only no_namespace
```

The tlb file does not seem to be getting updated either :(

Comment: I guess you simply have two copies of .tlb file of which one is actually updated when you recompile the COM server and the other one you #import. You need to import exactly the .tlb file that is produces when compiling the .idl file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.tlh` and `.tli` file should be updated when the `.tlb` timestamp has changed and you're `#import`ing it.  The `.tlb` file is the output when compiling the `.idl` file.  So you should check

- if the compile-settings for the `.idl` file are correct (configuration-dependent!)
- if the `.tlb` imported is really the same as the one compiled (check the include paths), as *sharptooth* described in the comment.

Beyond that, clearing/deleting all output-files manually sometimes makes a difference.  Although, I've to say, the usual problem with the MS toolchain using the project-files is that it is recompiling too often instead not often enough, so beyond configuration problems I've not had such a problem as you describe.

Comment: The error was solved with a reboot. Thank you for the information though.

Comment: I have run into a similar problem. It was caused by the #import-ing file not being rebuilt, so the import did no happen, thus the .tlh was not regenerated.